# Floating images (Daydream)

Tags: android

I have come across the hidden "Daydream" in android jellybean and i would like to know how i can make images or icons float across the screen "Activity" of my app when the user does not interact with it for 20 seconds, Is it possible? If so can somebody point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance I hope somebody can help.

I would like it to be kinda like the one in the image here "http://www.phonearena.com/news/Android-4.2-has-a-hidden-Jelly-Bean-Daydream_id36686"

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial seems to describe exactly what you want to do.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html